# Combine wdSeparateByTabs and wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator= "|" while executing ConvertTblsToText()

Tags: vba, text, ms-word

I am trying to get a way to combine  wdSeparateByTabs and wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator= "|" while converting a word document which has tables to a text file. Because I am still learning VBA, Could anyone help me?

Here are the codes which was used:

```
Sub ConvertTblsToText()

‘Convert all tables to text.

Dim tbl As table

If ActiveDocument.tables.Count = 0 Then

MsgBox “There are no tables in this document.”, vbOKOnly, “Error”

Exit Sub

End If

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.tables

‘wdSeparateByCommas, wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator,

‘wdSeparateByParagraphs, wdSeparateByTabs

tbl.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs

Next

End Sub
```

and to include "|"
This code :

```
Sub text_zu_tabelle()
Dim meinetabelle As Table
Application.DefaultTableSeparator = "*"
Set meinetabelle = Selection.ConvertToTable(Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator)
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, but it seems all you need is:

```
Sub ConvertTblsToText()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  If .Tables.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no tables in this document.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Do While .Tables.Count > 0
    .Tables(1).ConvertToText Separator:="|"
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Applying the code, my document went blank and cannot be accessed. Are these codes responsible for them? 

How to retrieve the document?

Comment: Those changes have no effect on your document. All they do is stop screen flicker while the code runs.

Comment: Thank you, this helped.
Good day to you.